# Exporting a global anonymous object doesn't work when I try to require a specific function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let us say I have a project with this structure:

```
lib/
  api.js
  thing.js
index.js
```

The code for each module is as follows (simplified without losing the sense of the thing).

```
/* lib/api.js */
"use strict";

var Api = function() {

};

Api.prototype.authenticate = function(credentials) {
  var self = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    self.token = {
      id: 1,
      token: "somesortoftoken"
    };
    resolve();
  });
};

Api.prototype.request = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(self.token);
    if (self.token) {
      resolve("success");
    }else{
      reject("failure");
    }
  });
};

module.exports = new Api();
```

The purpose of exporting with the `new` keyword is to ensure the same object is always returned, because I want to authenticate once and retain the authenticated api object.

The next module calls the API to make a request. Note that I require the api and then call the function `request` on it.

```
/* lib/thing.js */
"use strict";

var api = require('./api.js');

var thing = {

  storeThing: function(thingData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      api.request(thingData).then(result => {
        resolve(result);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    });
  }

};

module.exports = thing;
```

Finally I have an entry point which authenticates with the API and then calls the `thing` library.

```
/* index.js */
"use strict";

var api = require('./lib/api.js');
var libThing = require('./lib/thing.js');
var credentials = {
  username: "test@test.com",
  password: "password"
};

api.authenticate(credentials).then(result => {
  return libThing.storeThing({ id: 1 });
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

This works. I can require `api.js` from anywhere in the project and it will work as expected. However if I try the following change in `lib/thing.js` then it fails:

```
 /* lib/thing.js */
"use strict";

var request = require('./api.js').request;

var thing = {

  storeThing: function(thingData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(thingData).then(result => {
        resolve(result);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    });
  }

};

module.exports = thing;
```

From what I can diagnose the `request` function returned has an `undefined` this, so obviously no properties can be accessed.

I feel like this is something I ought to understand, but actually I can't see why it is so. If `require('./api.js')` returns the same global object, then why `require('./api.js').request` would not return a function derived from that object escapes me. Is it something to do with when it is evaluated or something more obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are changing of `this` context when referring an object property function.

In that case, `this` is bound to global object.

Comment: I'd love to understand the detail of this. When I call `api.request` in the original code, the context of `this` is determined by the object I call the method on. Why does that context change in the code outside the exported object (i.e. in the main part of the module?).

Comment: Because this is how engine treats this. It is based of the spec. This is a nice article which explains this context binding pretty well : http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Comment: Interesting thanks. I also see that in fact in strict mode (which I am using) the context is actually undefined. Give me a little time to digest this whole article :) I'll be back.

Comment: I know this is the answer (and I have so voted) but I still struggle to understand why in the context of a node module, the context of a function called on an object should not be that of the object itself. I still haven't truly "got" it. But it's clear you're correct.

Comment: @DanielC the thing is that I haven't understood it very well, but with what I understood is that object properties are only identifier of something, they never cary an actual value. Now since you are detaching completely from it's parent object, scope will never be able to find out what to bind on this. I highly recommend this book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033738.do